# Why won't Excel VBA accept my user defined variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently written some code that finds a value in a worksheet. If said value exists, it offsets the active cell to the first row. If the value doesn't exist, it displays an error message. I'm having an issue where it is rejecting my variable because of either a "runtime 91 error" or a compile error that requires an object. I am new to VBA, per chance might anyone know what this error is asking for. Below is my code for facilitated viewing.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim IDNUM As Boolean
    Set IDNUM = Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V:V").Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, , , LookAt:=xlWhole).Select

    If IDNUM = False Then
        MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
    Else
        ActiveCell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) It's a `Boolean`, so is only going to accept `TRUE/FALSE`, 2) You're using `Find()` which results in a `Range()`, except 3) You're trying to `.Select` the same time you're trying to set a variable...I think you want `Dim IDNUM as Range // Set IDNum = Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V:V").Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, , , LookAt:=xlWhole)`, then `If IDNum.Value = False` (or perhaps `"False"`)....And finally, I suggest reading through [how to avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim IDNUM As Boolean
```

This declares the identifier `IDNUM` and allocates it enough memory to store a `Boolean` value for it. Note that the possible Boolean values are `True` and `False`.

```
Set IDNUM = ...
```

This is a `Set` assignment, which means VBA will be expecting the left-hand side of the assignment operator (that's `=`) to be a *reference* type (i.e. an object reference). But `IDNUM` is a `Boolean`, so the `Set` assignment is illegal.

You want this to be a *value* assignment:

```
Let IDNUM = ...
```

But then, the `Let` keyword is redundant/obsolete, so you can just do:

```
IDNUM = ...
```

Now, the *right*-hand side of the assignment is also problematic:

```
Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V:V") _
                       .Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, , , LookAt:=xlWhole) _
                       .Select
```

First, the expression has no defined type: the `(Range).Select` method returns no value, so the expression can't legally appear to the right of an `=` operator.

`(Range).Find` *does* return something though - but it returns a `Range` object reference, and when it can't find what it's looking for, it returns `Nothing` - a special reference value that basically means "there's no object here", and any member call (like `.Select`) made against `Nothing` will always raise run-time error 91. NEVER assume `Range.Find` will return a valid object reference.

Instead, capture the search result into an object variable:

```
Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V:V").Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Note that because you're using *named arguments*, you don't need to specify the optional empty positional ones. That said `Range.Find` will use unspecified defaults for every single one of the optional parameters you're not specifying, so the recommendation is to ALWAYS provide every single one of them - otherwise you're at the mercy of whatever the user did last time they hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

IF the returned object isn't `Nothing`, *then* you can use it:

```
If Not findResult Is Nothing Then
    IDNUM = findResult.Value 'not sure what you mean to do here
Else
    'no found. now what?
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Lastly, note that `If {bool-expression} = {True|False} Then` is redundant: a Boolean value *is* a Boolean expression, so the comparison to a `True` or `False` literal is entirely redundant. Use the `Not` logical operator instead of comparing to `False`:

```
If Not IDNUM Then
    MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Activate
End If
```

...and consider avoiding negatives by putting the "nope" case last and reversing the condition:

```
If IDNUM Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -21).Activate
Else
    MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
End If
```

Note that the `ActiveCell` is *already* active - `ActiveCell.Activate` does nothing.

...and you don't need to care for the `ActiveCell` at all - the cell you want is the `findResult` range:

```
If IDNUM Then
    findResult.Offset(0, -21).Activate
Else
    MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
End If
```

Recap:

```
Dim findResult As Range
Set findResult = Worksheets("Petrobras").Range("V:V").Find(TXTOPPNUM_Insert.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not findResult Is Nothing Then
    If CBool(findResult.Value) Then
        findResult.Offset(0, -21).Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "This Opportunity has Not Been Registered Yet"
    End If
End If

End If
```